# Inserting data into 2 mysql table is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into mysql database. 
Data comes from`POST` and post array look like this -

```
Array
(
    [category_name] => main category
    [subCategory] => Array
        (
            [0] => Subcategory 01
            [1] => Subcategory 02
            [2] => Subcategory 03
        )

    [category-submitted] => TRUE
)
```

I am using two tables, one for category and other one for subcategory.

This is how I use `PHP` to insert these data:

```
// Insert the category into the database 
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO category (category) VALUES (?)";

// Prepare the statement:
$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insertQuery);

// Bind the variables:
$insert_stmt->bind_param('s', $category);

// Execute the prepared query.
if ($insert_stmt->execute()) { 
    //echo 'category added';        
    $last_catid = $insert_stmt->insert_id;

    if(!empty( $subcategories)) {

        // loop over the array insert subcategory
        foreach( $subcategories as $value ){
    $insertsubcatQuery = "INSERT INTO subcategory (category_id, subcategory) VALUES (?, ?)";

            // Prepare the statement:
            $insert_sub_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insertsubcatQuery);

            // Bind the variables:
            $insert_sub_stmt->bind_param('is', $last_catid, $value);

            // Execute the prepared query.
            if ($insert_sub_stmt->execute()) { 
                echo 'subcategory added';
            }           

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** This is how data comes to `$subcategories`:

```
$subCategory = $_POST['subCategory'];
$subcategories = array();
if (!empty( $subCategory ) && is_array( $subCategory )) {
    foreach( $subCategory as $key => $value ) {
        $subCategories[] = filter_var( $value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    }
}
```

But using this script its inserting category into database but not inserting subcategories into database. 
Can anybody tell me what is the wrong with this Code?

Thank you.

Comment: You should check for errors

Comment: @Jens, I cannot get any errors when running this script

Comment: Are you seeing your echo output?

Comment: no it not echoing 'echo 'subcategory added';`

Comment: That's not the full code, where do you define `$subcategories`, why do you use only the `value` in the `foreach` loop? Also, `not inserting subcategories` means "no new records" or "empty records" ?

Comment: @OfirBaruch, I updated my question with how I define `$subcategories`. There is no any new records in `subcategory` table

Comment: Did you used  $insert_sub_stmt->close(); after execute command...That might be solved your problem...

Comment: Please notice the capital C: `$subCategories[]` vs. `foreach($subcategories ...`

Comment: @OfirBaruch, yes I had a mistake. That was the problem. Now its working. Thank you.

Comment: Would it be OK if I write it as an answer and you'd approve it?

Comment: definitely. Its better if you show me, if it has a better  way do this than I have done. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, added the answer and few advises :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was a typo mistake in the variable's name.

Defining the `subCategories` variable:

```
$subcategories = array(); //Lower case c
if (!empty( $subCategory ) && is_array( $subCategory )) {
    foreach( $subCategory as $key => $value ) {
        $subCategories[] = filter_var( $value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ); //Capital C
    }
}
```

Inside the `insert` code:

```
if(!empty( $subcategories)) { //Lower case c

    // loop over the array insert subcategory
    foreach( $subcategories as $value ){ //Lower case c
```

**Code advice:**

You have 2 loops, one for filtering and building the subcategories array and another one that loop trough that array. You can combine them into an one array.

**Semantics advice:**

Regarding your database tables, I'll advise you to use more appropriate names.
For instance, the table that holds the categories should be plural, `categories`. The field `category` should be named `name`. The same goes for the `subcategory` table. (the `category_id` field is fine).